# Merge tags [javascript-automation] and [jxa], or make them synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both tags refer to the exact same technology (a JavaScript implementation of Apple's OSA (Open Scripting Architecture), available since OS X 10.10), succinctly described in [javascript-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-automation)

Given that "JXA" is a concise, readily recognizable initialism [used by Apple itself](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH111-SW1), I suggest:

- merging the tags as [jxa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxa), using the (better) tag description from [javascript-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-automation).
- alternatively, at least making them synonyms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make the \[jxa\] and \[javascript-automation\] tags synonyms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301066/make-the-jxa-and-javascript-automation-tags-synonyms)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Absolutely a duplicate (mea culpa), but I hope CristianCiupitu won't mind sticking with _this_ request, because it is more detailed.

Comment: Sure, do it however you choose.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I don't care which question gets closed, the important thing is to solve the issue :-)

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Glad to hear it. If you agree that my request captures the spirit of yours _and_ adds additional information, please use the `delete` link on _your_ request to delete it. Separately, feel free to add more information here.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: I just learned that someone with 2.5k+ reputation and at least 5 reputation points relating to the tag of interest can propose that 2 tags be considered synonyms - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms. We both have the overall reputation, but seem to lack points in either tag at the moment, but once we do, we can make this proposal (which then requires 4 votes to be accepted). Let's try to let each other know once we've managed to make that proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added [jxa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxa) as a synonym for [javascript-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-automation), instead of the other way round (even though [jxa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxa) had more questions), because:

1. As you mentioned the tag wiki for [javascript-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-automation) seemed more clear and well explained.
2. The tag as such is more self-explanatory than the JXA tag.

The tags are now synonymized as: [javascript-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-automation) (× 85) ← [jxa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxa) (× 149). Let me know if the the direction needs to be swapped. I'll merge the tags after a few days.